# Save wxWidgets window screenshot

Tags: c++, screenshot, wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets application. I wan't to get the window screen as image and save it into a file.

I know that the `wxImage` can be saved easily:

```
wxImage im;
im.Create(window_width, window_height)
/**assign some data**/
im.SaveFile("path/screen.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

However, how do I gather the window (**and I want only the window!**) pixel data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `wxClientDC` to access the window data. Then just `Blit()` them to a `wxMemoryDC` with a `wxBitmap` selected into it and finally convert the bitmap to `wxImage`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some detailed code showing how to do this - it is the second article down.

http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=32313

Comment: Oh, and I searched the forum using andvanced search and didn't find it :(

Comment: Using this brought screenshots of whole screen instead of window. Also the screenshots are useless - they contain a lot of empty, transparent areas. I don't understand what does the application actually capture.